# Strava Api token Android

Tags: android, multithreading, api, strava

I have authorized my app with Strava and i want to take my token from it.The problem is that in this code

```
 LoginResult result = api.getTokenForApp(AppCredentials.with(29519, "8d55af50a97a9f4b5269670de00bf5e6f4b9942d "))
                                .withCode(code)
                                .execute();
```

i think it never runs because i can't see the test5 printed.It goes directly to the intent outside the thread.Also how can i get the **result** from **LoginResult** outside my thread and my class and use it?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d("Strava code", "TEST1");


        if(requestCode == RQ_LOGIN && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try  {
                        String code = data.getStringExtra(StravaLoginActivity.RESULT_CODE);
                        Log.d("Strava code", "TEST2");

                        AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.create()
                                .debug()
                                .build();
                        Log.d("Strava code", "TEST3");

                        AuthenticationAPI api = new AuthenticationAPI(config);
                        Log.d("Strava code", "TEST4");

                        LoginResult result = api.getTokenForApp(AppCredentials.with(29519, "8d55af50a97a9f4b5269670de00bf5e6f4b9942d "))
                                .withCode(code)
                                .execute();
                        Log.d("Strava code", "TEST5");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });

            thread.start();

            Intent testInt= new Intent(MainActivity.this,TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(testInt);

        }
```